# how to change the heading of CActiveDataProvider in yii

Tags: yii

I am using `CActiveDataProvider` to show data in the index action. It displays the records nice but I want to change the heading of the list. i.e. I have a model `project`, so I write in controller:

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Project');
    $this->render('index',array(
        'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    ));
}
```

As output I found as the word `Projects` in `h1` tag as heading of the project's list. Please the attachment: [image]. Please could help me how to change this heading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `H1` is probably in the `index.php` view for that controller. Look in the view file and just remove the html.